# Is there an additional value carried by fundamental particles (like spin for example) that acts like an ID?

Tags: atomic-physics, identical-particles

My question arose after reading this:

https://www.npr.org/sections/thesalt/2019/11/03/772030934/soups-on-and-on-thai-beef-noodle-brew-has-been-simmering-for-45-years

Synopsis: In perpetual stew they repeatedly use the same broth over and over for an extended duration of time.

According to the math here it's exceptionally unlikely any particles from the original broth remain:

https://old.reddit.com/r/theydidthemath/comments/vdbkkd/request_how_many_molecules_of_gas_from_my_cars/icju069/

https://old.reddit.com/r/NoStupidQuestions/comments/5zqj1c/if_ive_never_let_my_car_run_out_of_gas_how_much/df0683e/

But this got me wondering about a scenario.

Say some random person ate the original soup 45 years ago and some of the original particles lodged themselves deep inside an organ like their bones. 1 year ago this person died and asked to be cremated and their ashes were spread into a river. That river was used to irrigate vegetables and one of those vegetables was composed of a few of the carbon atoms from the ashes. This vegetable then made it's way to the restaurant and is plopped back into the broth.

So now once again some of the truly original broth is there again.

But if this carbon atom were exactly the same as every other carbon atom it couldn't be the original, right? There has to be something that distinguishes it from the other carbon atoms. We tracked it and know that indeed it is an original carbon atom from the original soup, but how does the Universe "know?"

Comment: there are biological means that can store and replicate identifying information in chemical structure. DNA is one type of chemical ID. Not sure if all canned soup have these added too (by the manufacturer)

Comment: Not seeing why there are down votes. Questions like this have been asked before. https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/565203/

Comment: What I am actually asking is more along the lines of how you can have two completely identical DNA strands that exist down to the last fundamental particle remain completely distinct from each other when all of their "values" are the same. How does the Universe not get them mixed up? It would suggest to me anyway that each of these fundamental particles has a sort of "unique identifier."

Comment: @JackHulse at the smallest scale, i believe there is fundamental theory that there is no way one can distinguish between 2 electrons. "Electrons are identical particles because they cannot be distinguished from each other by their intrinsic physical properties. In quantum mechanics, this means that a pair of interacting electrons must be able to swap positions without an observable change to the state of the system." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron#:~:text=Electrons%20are%20identical%20particles%20because,the%20state%20of%20the%20system.

Comment: I guess that just gives me a further question. Imagine you have two electrons separated by a great distance. Since there is a minimum time if I am not mistaken (Planck time), when there is a transition from one of these time units to the next, if the electrons were exactly the same in everyway how can you be certain that the electron at location X didn't switch with the electron at location Y?

Comment: @JackHulse i think the wiki quote mean that, if we close our eyes for a moment and somebody switch the electrons, then there will be no way to test it has occurred. It does not imply the electrons *will* switch places by their own accord.

Comment: *"There has to be something that distinguishes it from the other carbon atoms."* Why? As far as we know, atoms don't have an ID, or any way to apply a permanent ID marker to them, although you can temporarily put them into various excited states. So if you get two atoms of carbon-12, put them into a box, shake them around a bit, then take them back out, there's no way to distinguish between them.

Comment: If everything/time is genuinely continuous I can see that there wouldn't be any issues with them not being distinguished. But if things are in anyway discreet it seems to me that there would be significant problems without some way of distinguishing one particle from the next. For instance what about entanglement? In a discreet system what would keep that entanglement property assigned to two particles between units of time and avoid it getting mixed up with another particle? You could again say that instead of the entanglement being linked to particles it could simply be based on locations

Comment: But if it was based on locations that would then imply that space itself rather than the particles would have another form of added information. Either way it seems to me that unless time is truly continuous there has to be extra information in someway otherwise things would be permitted to violate fundamental laws like the speed of light